# Object fit - unknown property

Tags: html, css, jsp

Is there an alternative to `object-fit: contain`? **Oracle JDeveloper 12 c** says "unknown property".

I want to scale an image with css to fill a div keeping the aspect ratio

```
info.push('<div class="compra-acti">');
    info.push('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 titulo">');
    desc=elem.descActiv; 
    info.push('<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 foto">');
    info.push('<img onerror="this.src=\"../images/img_arti.jpg\"" alt="'+desc+'" src="../loadImg.jspnomCache=<%=pNomCache%>&codiArticle='+elem.codiActiv+'&tipus=ARTICLE">');
info.push('<\/div>');


.compra-acti{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    min-height:80px;
}
.compra-acti img{
    max-height: 78px;
}

.compra-acti .foto{
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: What is "it"? Are you using one of the browsers which don't support `object-fit` property? https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: Oracle JDeveloper 12 c it says 'unkown property'. Also when I published my website, if I press F12 in the css I don't see the object-fit property.  I amb using Google Chrome 79

Comment: It's an acceptable value but your version of the software may not recognize it. you may require an update.